# Creating a list view tree structure in new asp.net app (first time)

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, html-lists

I was wondering if any one could help explain to me the best way to re create the code below in an asp.net application.

I would like to convert my current web based app to an asp app for use with an sql server on the company's intranet. It is currently using azure for its data source.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

This is the code i am using in the web application to create the ui that I would like to do in the asp.net app.

```
function createGuiItems(items) {

   var listItems = $.map(items, function (item) {

       if (item.painumber !== lastPai) {
           for (var member in itemList) delete itemList[member];
           elementToApended = $('<li></li>').append($('<details class="middle-div main-product-div" id="' + item.painumber + '"><summary class="main-summary">Show / Hide Product Details For Order No -' + item.painumber + ' - Dispatch Date - ' + item.dispatchdatetoshow +
               ((checkIfDueToday(item) === true) ? ' - <strong class="completion-due"> Due To Be Completed Today </strong>' : ' ') + '</summary></details>')
               .iff((item.emponjob === true) && (item.empworkcentre === selectedWorkCentre)).attr('open', 'open').end());
       }

                if (itemList.hasOwnProperty(item.productcode)) {
                    var thirdElementApended = $('<div class="middle-middle-div"></div>')
                    .attr('data-todoitem-id', item.id)
                    .attr('data-todoitem-pai', item.painumber)
                    .attr('data-todoitem-item', item.itemnumber)
                    .attr('data-todoitem-link', item.drawingurl)
                    .append($('<div class="item-div"></div>')
                    .append($('<div class="Pai-Head"></div>').append(item.painumber))
                    .append($('<div class="Item-Head"></div>').append(item.itemnumber))
                    .append($('<div class="Product-Head"></div>').append(item.productcode))
                    .append($('<div class="Size-Head"></div>').append(item.xsize + " X " + item.ysize))
                    .append($('<div class="Qty-Head"></div>').append(item.quantity))
                    .append($('<div class="Disp-Head"></div>').append(item.dispatchdatetoshow)))
                    .append($('<div class="Button-Head"></div>').append('<button class="new-ncr-button">Raise New NCR</button>').append('<button class="new-di-button">New Drawing Issue</button>').append('<button class="view-drawings-button">View Product Drawings</button>'))
                    .append($('<details class="mods-div"><summary class="mods-summary">Check The Modifications Here</summary></details>').append($('<div class="mods-text">').append(item.modifications)));
                    $(elementToApended).find('#' + item.productcode).append(thirdElementApended)
                } else {
                    var secondElementApended = $('<details class="middle-div sub-product-div" id="' + item.productcode + '"><summary>' + item.painumber + ' - ' + item.productcode + '</summary></details>')
                    .iff((item.emponjob === true) && (item.empworkcentre === selectedWorkCentre)).attr('open', 'open').end()
                    .attr('data-todoitem-pai', item.painumber)
                    .attr('data-todoitem-prco', item.productcode)
                    .append($('<div class="job-tools-div"></div>')
                    .append('<button class="positive ui button mini' + ((item.emponjob === true) && (item.empworkcentre === selectedWorkCentre) ? ' loading ' : ' ') + 'StartButton">Start Manufacturing</button>')
                    .append('<button class="negative ui button mini StopButton">Stop Manufacturing</button>').iff((item.emponjob === true) || (item.emponjob === false) && (item.empworkcentre === selectedWorkCentre))
                    .append('<button class="ui primary button mini CompleteButton">Manufacturing Complete</button>').end())
                    .append($('<div class="middle-middle-div"></div>')
                    .attr('data-todoitem-id', item.id)
                    .attr('data-todoitem-pai', item.painumber)
                    .attr('data-todoitem-item', item.itemnumber)
                    .attr('data-todoitem-link', item.drawingurl)
                    .append($('<div class="item-div"></div>').append($('<div class="Pai-Head"></div>').append(item.painumber))
                    .append($('<div class="Item-Head"></div>').append(item.itemnumber))
                    .append($('<div class="Product-Head"></div>').append(item.productcode))
                    .append($('<div class="Size-Head"></div>').append(item.xsize + " X " + item.ysize))
                    .append($('<div class="Qty-Head"></div>').append(item.quantity))
                    .append($('<div class="Disp-Head"></div>').append(item.dispatchdatetoshow)))
                    .append($('<div class="Button-Head"></div>').append('<button class="new-ncr-button">Raise New NCR</button>').append('<button class="new-di-button">New Drawing Issue</button>').append('<button class="view-drawings-button">View Product Drawings</button>'))
                    .append($('<details class="mods-div"><summary class="mods-summary">Check The Modifications Here</summary></details>').append($('<div class="mods-text">').append(item.modifications))));
                    $(elementToApended).find('#' + item.painumber).append(secondElementApended)
                    itemList[item.productcode] = 1;
                }

                if (item.painumber !== lastPai) {
                    lastPai = item.painumber;
                    return elementToApended;
                } else {
                    lastPai = item.painumber;
                };


    }, handleError);

}
```

Comment: Also the data comes from a single table

Comment: Asp.Net is a web app and you can use javascript. If your data is hooked up correctly, you should be able to just drop this code in. Nobody on SO is going to rewrite this for you in vb.

Comment: Crowcoder thanks for the response maybe I have been a bit vague I don't want a re write of the code I just wanted to know what was best practice ie does the code need to be re written or can it still be used as is.